# Call Post Object ID in the function ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Field pro version and using Post Object to select multiple posts. I have a function in header.php which passes site url and unique code which is auto generated, the function name is Generate($id) which is working fine.

When i use post object i dont know how to call function in postobject.

what i a have tried in the code is below:

```
$post_objects = get_field('post_objects'); 
if( $post_objects ): ?> 
<ul>
 <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo Generate($id); ?>"><?php echo 
     get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a> 
   <span>Post Object Custom Field: <?php the_field('field_name', 
    $post_object->ID); ?></span> 
    </li> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
 </ul> 
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Its showing the link but not passing site url... how can i put post_object>id in the a href link.

Thanks

Comment: There's no code attached

Comment: @NathanDawson I dont know how put code properly :(

Comment: @Atif please put it in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: @iehrlich I did :)

Comment: Shouldn't `Generate($id)` be `Generate($post_object->ID)`? Also, shouldn't you be using `get_permalink()` instead? And why is `Generate()` capitalised?

Comment: @powerbuoy i have created a function which generate unique id, pass site url... so everytim i call a function instead of put unique id var plus url

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell you thing the function name is Generate($id) so with this id all link shows differen.